# malloc in stderr when capturing response in subprocess.run

Tags: python, subprocess, malloc

I'm trying execute a certain command using subprocess.run and get its output in python 3.10.12.

When run directly in linux terminal, the command runs a executable which reads some sensor values and prints execution time and sensor readings in binary.

Code used is below :

```
command = ["communicator","run","-d","9"]
result = subprocess.run(command,shell = True, capture_output=True)
print(f"STDOUT : {result.stdout}.")
print(f"STDERR : {result.stderr}.")
```

The -d argument specifies how many bytes are returned.

with output of command has an odd number of bytes returned, this works fine and valid results are returned.

Example 1 :

> STDOUT : b'Execution time: 626 ms\n       0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  a  b  c  d  e  f\n0000: 5c 5c 28                                         "\\(\xb3"\n'.
> STDERR : b'Result : 0x0\n'.

Example 2 :

> STDOUT : b'Execution time: 540 ms\n       0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  a  b  c  d  e  f\n0000: 5c 1c 28 10 41                                   "\.(.A\x7f"\n'
> STDERR : b'Result: 0x0\n'

However, with even number of bytes returned, I see a malloc in stderr :

> STDOUT : b''.
> STDERR : b'malloc(): corrupted top size\nAborted (core dumped)\n'.

The malloc is seen when the return has 4,6,8... bytes.

When the cmd is run without capture_output (i.e. capture_output = False), valid output is seen irrespective of the number of bytes returned. Similarly, when command is run directly in terminal, valid output is seen for both even and odd number of bytes returned.
Due to this, I suspect the issue occurs when subprocess  attempts to capture the output, but I am having a hard time trying to further debug/workaround this.

How might I know what causes the malloc corruption and capture the command's output irrespective of the return size?

Comment: What if you ran on the command line but piped stdout and stderr to files? Or piped them to some other command? That would be more like the non-tty environment you'd get in python.